# ATM CodeChef only returns 0.00

Tags: c

I am new to programming and am attempting to solve a CodeChef problem in C. Here is link to problem:https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST Program should read in a withdrawal amount from an ATM and display new balance minus withdrawal fee. Original balance is <= 2000. Below is the code I currently have. Output is currently 0.00 for all withdrawal amounts.

```
int main() {

int withdrawAmount; 
float withdrawFee = 0.5;
const int beginAccountBalance = 2000;
float endAccountBalance; 

printf("How much do you wish to withdraw? ");
scanf("%", withdrawAmount); 

if((withdrawAmount %5 == 0)&&(0 < withdrawAmount <= beginAccountBalance))
{ 
    endAccountBalance = beginAccountBalance - withdrawAmount - withdrawFee; 
    printf("Account Balance is %.2f", endAccountBalance);
}
else {
    printf("Account Balance is %.2f", beginAccountBalance);
}    
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `0 < withdrawAmount <= beginAccountBalance` doesn't do what you think it does.  Use something like `0 < withdrawAmount && withdrawAmount <= beginAccountBalance`.

Comment: `scanf("%", withdrawAmount);`  --> `if( 1 != scanf("%d", &withdrawAmount)) return -1;`

Comment: Do **not** use fixed size floating point with currencies or else where you need exact values.

Comment: `printf("Account Balance is %.2f", beginAccountBalance);` uses the wrong format specifier (since `beginAccountBalance` is `int` not `double` or `float`).  Try `printf("Account Balance is %d.00", beginAccountBalance);` or even `printf("Account Balance is %.2f", (double)beginAccountBalance);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason why things aren't going well for you is due to your usage of `scanf`.

```
scanf("%", withdrawAmount);
```

There are two problems with your usage:

1. After the `%`, you forgot to put an identifier (identifiers being not unlike the ones you used in your `printf` calls). In your case, all you need to do to correct this is change `%` to `%d`. `%d` basically tells `scanf` to scan for an integer, which is the data type that `withdrawAmount` is.

If you need information on standard C functions, [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) serves as an excellent reference to function usage. I would see their page on [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) to read up on identifiers used by `scanf`.

2. When you passed `withdrawAmount` as an argument to `scanf`, you did not put an `&` before the variable. The `&` operator in front of a variable basically retrieves the address of the variable it is used on. You need to use this with `scanf` because `scanf` basically takes the memory address of the variable you give it, and when it scans standard input (terminal entries in your case), it stashes values of the data it finds into the memory address you give it.

Therefore,

```
scanf("%", withdrawAmount);
```

should be changed to

```
scanf("%d", &withdrawAmount);
```

I leave you to figure out whether your implementation is mathematically sound. Keep up the hard work!